# Trigger build of Github Pages site from headless Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nuxt.js, github-pages, webhooks

I'm exploring the possibility of having a headless Wordpress installation running on a certain domain and whenever something is created or changed in the database it would send a webhook to Github Pages that then would build a static site based on the WP content, with Nuxt.js.

There is this Wordpress plugin called [wp-headless-trigger](https://github.com/nicoandrade/wp-headless-trigger) that lets you enter a webhook URL that will be triggered whenever you create or update a post, page or custom post type. It surely works great with Netlify, Vercel and similar, but is it possible to trigger Github Pages? In that case it would require some kind of URL that triggers a Github Action, if I've understood it correctly.

Is this approach even possible with Github Pages or is there any other way to automatically trigger a build on Github Pages from Wordpress when updated?

Comment: Hi, did this later work? I am thinking of how I can achieve something like this, I want to trigger build whenever there is a new post is published on WordPress